# 2x2 table with frequency and overall percentage in SAS - proc tabulate?

Tags: sas

I have a set of pre and post scores, with values that can be 1 or 2, e.g.:
Pre Post
1  2
1  1
2  2
2  1
1  2
2  1
etc.

I need to create a 2x2 table that lists the frequencies, with percentages ONLY in the total row/column:

```
           1           2       Total
1         14          60      74 / 30%
2         38          12      50 / 20%
Total   52 / 21%    72 / 29%    248
```

It doesn't need to be formatted specifically with the / between the n and percent, they can be on different lines. I just need to make sure the total percentages (no cumulative percentages) are in the table.

I think that I should use proc tabulate to get this, but I'm new to SAS and haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code I've tried:

```
proc tabulate data=.bilirubin order=data; 
   class pre ; 
   var post ; 
   table pre , post*( n colpctsum); 
run;
```

Comment: What have you tried in `PROC TABULATE` so far?   You're certainly correct it is possible to do there.

Comment: The only thing I've gotten to run is this, but it doesn't give me a 2x2 table or give me the percentages in the bottom row: 
proc tabulate data=.bilirubin order=data;
 class pre ;
 var post ;
 table pre , post*( n colpctsum);
run;

Comment: Try PROC FREQ instead?You can control the percents reported with OUTPCT

Comment: I tried many variations on that, too, but I couldn't figure out how to get the percentages only for the totals. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own report. For example you could use PROC SUMMARY to get frequencies. Add a data step to calculate the percent and generate a character variable with the text you want to display. Then use PROC REPORT to display it.

```
proc summary data=have ;
  class pre post ;
  output out=summary ;
run;
proc format ;
  value total .='Total (%)';
run;
data results ;
  set summary ;
  length display $20 ;
  if _type_=0 then n=_freq_;
  retain n;
  if _type_ in (0,3) then display = put(_freq_,comma9.);
  else display = catx(' ',put(_freq_,comma9.),cats('(',put(_freq_/n,percent8.2),')'));
run;
proc report  missing data=results ;
  column pre display,post n ;
  define pre / group ;
  define post / across ;
  define n / noprint ;
  define display / display ' ';
  format pre post total.;
run;
```

[image]